# Laravel Has Many Through relation

Tags: php, laravel

That's my table:

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
```

In my case I just want to list the posts in the country where like '%keyword%'. I have defined on the country model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
   /**
     * Get all of the posts for the country.
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'App\User');
    }
}?>
```

Now,the user will input a country name or a  post title keyword to search the posts.My controller:

```
public function posts()
{
    $param = Input::all();

    if (isset($param['country']) && $param['country']) {
        $query = Posts::whereHas('country', function($q) use ($param) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $param['country'] . '%');
        });
    }   
}
```

How to define country relation in posts model?belongToThrough has tried but not work.Many tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're facing is that there is no reverse of the "hasManyThrough" relationship, i.e. there is no such thing as "belongsToThrough".

You will probably have do to this with an explicit join, e.g.

```
$query = Post::where('countries.name', 'like', '%' . $param['country'] .'%')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
```